# JQuery Ajax POST call not sending parameters correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to learn Ajax and have some problem with how to send the request from the client.

I have a jsp at "/web" on my local server that handles requests (Not sure if this is best practise, or if it should be handled in a servlet, but it's just a mockup so I guess it's ok). The code for the jsp is like this:

```
<%!
int i;
public void jspInit() {    
    i = 0;
    System.out.println("Initialized");
}
%>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>My web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String content = request.getParameter("content");
            System.out.println("Processed " + content); i++; %>
        <%= "Hello World " + i %> 
        <br>
        You sent me the text: <%= content %>
    </body> 
</html>
```

and the function for sending the request on client side is:

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    sentData = {content: "Test data to send"};
        $.post({
            url: '/web',
            data: JSON.stringify(sentData),
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(data) {
            $("#form").html("Sent from client: " + sentData.content + "<br>" + "Recieved from server:<br>" + data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#form").html("Could not send message.");
        }
    });
```

This however gives the output

```
Sent from client: Test data to send
Received from server:
Hello World 2 
You sent me the text: null
```

on the client, and the System.out.println on the server only writes "Processed null" when the request is sent. I guess I am doing something wrong when sending the data through JQuery.

Sending the data through the URL address "[mydomain]/web/?content=Test+data+to+send" gives the expected output

```
Hello World 2 
You sent me the text: Test data to send
```

as does sending a POST request through tools like Postman, so I imagine the server side is set up correctly. What am I doing wrong at the JQuery request? I have also tried some more simple calls like this:

```
$("#send").click(function() {
    sentData = {content: "Test data to send"};
    $.post({
        url: '/web',
        data: sentData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#form").html("Sent from client: " + sentData.content + "<br>" + "Recieved from server:<br>" + data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#form").html("Could not send message.");
        }
    });
});
```

with the same result.

Comment: You're explicitely stating `contentType: "application/json"` but you're sending a string...

Comment: I have never seen `$.post` used with a full jQuery ajax object as argument, and i don't see it in the docs. Have you tried to use `$.ajax` instead? (syntax for parameters for `$.post` should rather be `$.post(url, {param, 'test'});`

Comment: I'm not a PHP dev, but is this the correct way to get the BODY of a request.. `request.getParameter`.. That sounds like it's meant for query parameters.

Comment: As far as I can see, all you need to do is replace `data: JSON.stringify(sentData),` with `data: sentData,`

Comment: Kaddath: Changing the post call to $.post('/web', {content: "Test data to send"}) did not work for me either. Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I just noticed now (i go slow sometimes), you are sending with `post`, which is OK, but you may try to retreive a `get` parameter (we don't know what's in `getParameter`), which won't exist in a post request. Get and post parameters don't arrive in the same arrays in PHP (`$_GET` / `$_POST`)

Comment: I think I in this case have to send it through POST, since I want it to follow the REST way of doing things and I'm actually sending things to the server (and processing it). I also thought it could be something with GET/POST, but sending a POST request through the tool Postman with parameters content: "sample text" gives the right output on the server.

As a side note, I don't do anything in PHP (unless the jsp/tomcat uses it under the hood) since it's received in a Java Server Pages file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to send object instead of string:

```
...
data: {content: "Test data to send"},
dataType: 'json'
...
```

Comment: Same result for me, maybe it is something to do with receiving the data as parameters instead of in BODY?